# In android how to place components in a listview with items?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using a listview with listitems and there is a need for me to add button near each listitem. How can i make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have your own `custom adapter` and in that you have to set the layout in the `getView()` method. Now in the layout file that is the xml file keep the button.